# How can I write blob data to a file with ruby?

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, blob

I'm trying to download all of our information off of a really lousy cloud server. The files are images and PDFs. My problem is that I don't know how to write the blob data that I receive from the `read_object` call I do via this cloud API out to a file on my local filesystem.

I know that I could use ImageMagick/RMagick to create an image from the blob, but I would rather just skip this step and write the data directly to a file. I don't want to have to worry about having ImageMagick compiled with every single decode delegate ever.

I don't really see much information on Google for this, is this something that is just not done often with Ruby?

Comment: I think you have to use binary write mode, `b` when opening a file, then just write to it. Not 100% sure though. Should be somewhere in the IO docs.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Assuming the file doesn't exist or you want to overwrite its current content, you just need to open the file with mode `wb` (`w` for write, `b` for binary — the `b` may not be strictly necessary on all systems). If you're trying to append to a file, use `ab` instead. See [this page](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/IO.html#method-c-new-label-IO+Open+Mode) for more information on modes.

```
File.open(filename, 'wb') do |f|
  f.write blob
end
```